# resizable box-drawing in the terminal

Tags: command-line-interface, window-resize, ansi-escape, termios

I'm currently trying to do pretty cli apps, my goal is to make a box that makes the whole outline of the terminal.

What I currently do:

- Grab the size of the terminal
- Draw the top line : top-left corner + (width - 2) * top edge + top-right corner
- Draw left and right borders : "\r\n|" + (width - 2) * " " + "|"
- Draw the bottom line :  bottom-left corner + (width - 2) * top edge + bottom-left corner

And I put all this in a loop and refresh it 30 times per second.
The problem is that when the terminal is resized, some edges are offset and displayed in the middle of the screen for a small amount of time.

How can you avoid these small glitches ?
Is it possible to tell the terminal to not display anything while the user is resizing or something like that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question:

> How can you avoid these small glitches ? Is it possible to tell the terminal to not display anything while the user is resizing or something like that ?

You can't *entirely* avoid that.  Applications which deal with window-resizing catch `SIGWINCH` (rather than relying on repeatedly checking the size), and repaint the screen.  If that is "fast enough", it is not really noticeable.

When catching `SIGWINCH`, it is also possible for those to arrive too frequently to respond to each one.  An application has to allow for that (by omitting repainting when it starts to fall behind).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is indeed a better way to handle a screen resize. I tried to make it so that when a first SIGWINCH is catched the screen is cleared and after some time without SIGWINCH I redraw the frame. It removes most of the artifacts but not all, but I guess it is all about timing things right.